# Day to day price movements

Tags: stocks, technical-analysis

Are day to day price movements for a stock driven mainly by the market movement or stock specific resistance, support etc.?

Comment: Nobody knows, at all.  It is utterly mysterious.  Note that if anyone "knew the answer" to this question, they would within days be the richest and most powerful human who has ever lived.

Answer (score 5):

The only accurate generalization you can make is that day to day movements are determined by supply and demand -- more buy side pressure increases it and more sell side pressure decreases it. Whether that's mostly driven by index fund movements, general market reasons, or stock specific reasons at any given time can only be guessed and analyzed on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2):

Many factors affect share price: Analyst recommendations, general news, earnings announcements, dividends, etc.  Even the market does as well: "A rising tide lifts all boats".

What they all have in common is that if there is more buying than selling volume then share price rises.  Conversely, it falls if there is more selling than buying volume.